# Changing a bash script to on all files together

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a bash script extracting some information from .vcf files. How I can change this script in a way to work on a bounch of .vcf files at the same time returning separate .txt output for each of them?

This is my script

```
#!/usr/bash

#outfilename
outname=$(echo $1".parsed.txt")

#Header for output file
echo -e "Chrom"'\t'"Position"'\t'"Ref"'\t'"Alt"'\t'"TumorReadCount"'\t'"TumorVariantAlleleCount"'\t'"TumorReferenceAlleleCount"'\t'"NormalReadCount"'\t'"NormalVariantAlleleCount"'\t'"NormalReferenceAlleleCount"'\t'"VAF" > $outname

while read -r line ; 
do;

#Basic information
chrom=$(echo $line | sed 's/ /\t/g' | cut -f 1) #&& echo $chrom;
Pos=$(echo $line | sed 's/ /\t/g' |  cut -f 2) #&& echo $Pos;
Ref=$(echo $line | sed 's/ /\t/g' | cut -f 4)
Alt=$(echo $line | sed 's/ /\t/g' | cut -f 5)

#Tumor sample read, variant and reference information
ReadCount=$(echo $line | cut -f 8 | sed 's/;/\t/g' | cut -f 13 | sed 's/ReadCount=//' )
VariantAlleleCount=$(echo $line | cut -f 8 | sed 's/;/\t/g' | cut -f 26| sed 's/VariantAlleleCount=//')
ReferenceAlleleCount=$(echo $ line | awk -v rc=$ReadCount -v vac=$VariantAlleleCount '{print rc-vac}')


#Control or Normal read, variant, reference information
ReadCountControl=$(echo $line | cut -f 8 | sed 's/;/\t/g' | cut -f 14 | sed 's/ReadCountControl=//')
VariantAlleleCountControl=$(echo $line | cut -f 8 | sed 's/;/\t/g' | cut -f 27 | sed 's/VariantAlleleCountControl=//')   

ReferenceAlleleCountControl=$(echo $line | awk -v rcc=$ReadCountControl -v vacc=$VariantAlleleCountControl '{print rcc-vacc}')


VAF=$(echo $line | cut -f 8 | sed 's/;/\t/g' | cut -f 28 | sed 's/VariantAlleleFrequency=//')
#Print output
echo -e $chrom'\t'$Pos'\t'$Ref'\t'$Alt'\t'$ReadCount'\t'$VariantAlleleCount'\t'$ReferenceAlleleCount'\t'$ReadCountControl'\t'$VariantAlleleCountControl'\t'$ReferenceAlleleCountControl'\t'$VAF >> $outname ;

#Remove info tags from VCF
done; < <( egrep -v '#' $1)
```

When I add `for f in *.vcf` returns

```
[fi1d18@cyan01 snp]$ bash vcf_parasing.sh
vcf_parasing.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
vcf_parasing.sh: line 7: `echo -e "Chrom"'\t'"Position"'\t'"Ref"'\t'dCount"'\t'"TumorVariantAlleleCount"'\t'"TumorReferenceAlleleCount"'\t'"NormalRelVariantAlleleCount"'\t'"NormalReferenceAlleleCount"'\t'"VAF" > $outname'
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a tool such as `awk` or `perl` to avoid the multiple `echo | cut | sed` commands. See for example [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before I go any further, I have to mention: use https://www.shellcheck.net/ - it will make debugging shell scripts much easier, and that's one of the tools I've used to answer your question. Now onto the actual problem.

If you look at the error output, you've missed a double quote here:

```
"Ref"'\t'dCount"'
```

For exactly the same reason - large amount of quotes and [portability of printf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/85039) - I'd suggest using `printf` command instead:

```
printf "Chrom\tPosition\tRef\tAlt\tTumorReadCount\tTumorVariantAlleleCount\tTumorReferenceAlleleCount\tNormalReadCount\tNormalVariantAlleleCount\tNormalReferenceAlleleCount\tVAF\n"
```

Among other things, please double quote the shell variables. If variable contain spaces, something known as word splitting will occur and produce unintended results, thus breaking your script. There are other [security concerns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) as well.

Another thing - use simple assignments and curly braces when appending text to variables:

```
outname="${1}.parsed.txt"
```

The reason for curly braces is this: without them it may be ambiguous to the shell where variable name ends and where plain text begins. Of course your original form with quoted `.parsed.txt` is fine, too, but curly braces are typically better and clearer.

There's other issues with the code, but I'll leave them to you to review via shellcheck.

<sub>Please note: I am not affiliated with shellcheck.net - I merely recommend a good tool that is used by me and other Linux users and does a good job for debugging scripts</sub>